# Can you convert a superclass

Tags: javascript

Can you convert a superclass reference into a subclass reference?  A subclass reference into a superclass reference?  If so, give examples.  If not, explain why not

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have typed references at all. An object reference is just an object reference, the full and complete extent of any type information it has is that it's an object reference. So there's no *need* to convert a reference from a superclass reference to a subclass reference.

The object itself (not the reference) does have some information that, in some ways, links it back to its "class" (which is to say, its constructor function), indirectly via its prototype — assuming that A) The prototype isn't changed via `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` (a reasonable assumption, but there's no guarantee), and B) the `prototype` property on the constructor function doesn't get changed (also frequently a reasonable assumption, but not a guarantee, once the codebase is done initializing [and not until then]). For instance, if an object is created via a constructor function, in the normal case it inherits a `constructor` property from its prototype which, in the normal case, points back at the constructor function. You can't really rely on it, because if someone has modified the object referenced by the constructor function's `prototype` property it may not have a `constructor` property at all (and thus inherits it from *its* prototype) or may have one pointing at the wrong function.

It's important to remember that JavaScript is a *prototypical* language, not a class-based one. The new class semantics in ES6 are almost entirely syntactic sugar for setting up chains of constructors and their prototypes. ("Almost" because there's some plumbing related to subclassing builtins like arrays that we couldn't do previously.) One aspect of JavaSCript not being class-based is that questions like this don't really relate to it.

Comment: thank you for answering ,so we dont need to convert  superclass reference into a subclass reference right.

Comment: @Amon: Right, they're just object references.